# Datagrid integrate in Album module zf2

Tags: datagrid, zend-framework2

How i can use datagrid in my Album module which is my basic module in my module section , Is it possible then how we use what to write in controller and in view for showing Album in datagrid please follow a stepetive process? Thank you...

Comment: show your code effort.

Comment: Please work yourself through the [official Documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). Don't start building a Car, if you can't even assemble a Bycicle :S

Comment: Sir, i know how to make a module but i am trying for 2 days on datagrid in my existing module that is the problem sir,  Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the Datagrid module for the zf2 from the following links:

1. [ZfcDatagrid](https://github.com/ThaDafinser/ZfcDatagrid) or
2. [zf2-datagrid](https://github.com/odiaseo/zf2-datagrid)

And here is the installation process for it: [datagrid installation](https://github.com/ThaDafinser/ZfcDatagrid#installation).

The screenshot is here: [ZfcDatagrid screenshots](https://github.com/ThaDafinser/ZfcDatagrid#screenshots).

And you can find the more tutorials [here](https://bitbucket.org/odiaseo/data-grid-for-zend-framework-2/src/ec40cc642df946094e7a619455649bcaba7441c6/README.md).

As here you have not post the code so I can help you by giving the links only.

Best of luck.